# SECRET_KEY variable is printing, but still receiving SECRET_KEY must not be empty error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, environment-variables

I am deploying my application to Heroku but when I attempt to push the code to Heroku, I receive the `The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.` error.

When I replace the SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY') with SECRET_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXX', there is no longer an error. I thought it would be that the my environment variable is not being read correctly and is returning None. However, when I use the shell to print my settings.SECRET_KEY while it's set to os.getenv('SECRET_KEY'), it prints my environment variable. Also, if I remove the `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, it appears to be working as well. I am not sure what is going on. I am on Windows by the way, working with Django 2.2.2 and Python 3.7.3.

Here is my settings.py:

```py
"""
Django settings for django_project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import django_heroku

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'bandwagonnba.herokuapp.com'
]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'bandwagon.apps.BandwagonConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'crispy_forms', 
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'storages',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'bandwagon-home'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_PASS')

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Below is the error I am receiving when I attempt to push the code.

```
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site- packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 204, in fetch_command
remote:            app_name = commands[subcommand]
remote:        KeyError: 'collectstatic'
remote:        During handling of the above exception, another exception 
occurred:
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
remote:            main()
remote:          File "manage.py", line 17, in main
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in 
execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site- packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
remote:            self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site- packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 211, in fetch_command
remote:            settings.INSTALLED_APPS
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site- packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
remote:            self._setup(name)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
remote:            self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 176, in __init__
remote:            raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must 
not be empty.")
remote:        django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY 
setting must not be empty.
```

Comment: DId you export your `SECRET_KEY` variable in Heroku? Since you're getting the value from env variables, you'd need to export that in Heroku.

Comment: The error is just a side effect of an other error. It looks like the collection of static files is not set up properly.

Comment: can you try putting the line `import django_heroku` at bottom, just before `django_heroku.settings(locals())`?

Comment: What did you do to add your secret key to Heroku?

Comment: Wow I feel so dumb for this. I set my secret key in heroku but I had to change it and when I thought I was updating it I entered the command to just delete the old one instead. Thank you to all of you! I adjusted the secret key in heroku and it worked fine